# i want to remove all zero from one list and append all of them to another list but not all of them remove

Tags: python, python-3.2

i want to remove all zero from one list and append them to another list,but when more than one zero come after each other,one of them,does not remove.

```
zero=[]
l=[2,3,6,0,0,5,6,0,7]
for i in l:
    if i==0:
        l.remove(i)
        zero.append(i)
print(l)
print(zero)


l=[2, 3, 6, 5, 6, 0, 7]
zer0=[0, 0]
```

in this out put,one of zero,does not remove

Comment: Welcome to StackOveflow sajjjad ! I suggest you to have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) after people has answered your question. It's better to accept a question when the answer solves your problem and/or upvote or downvote according to the answer content than to thank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are iterating through a list that you are modifying.
If you remove a current element from this list, it will shrink and `next(l)` will skip one element. To avoid it, always iterate through a copy of the list. For example `list(l)` or `l[:]`.

```
zero=[]
l=[2,3,6,0,0,5,6,0,7]
for i in list(l):
    if i==0:
        l.remove(i)
        zero.append(i)
print(l)
print(zero)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not modify a list while iterating the object. instead you can use a copy. `l[:]`

**Ex:**

```
zero=[]
l=[2,3,6,0,0,5,6,0,7]
for i in l[:]:
    if i==0:
        l.remove(i)
        zero.append(i)
print(l)
print(zero)
```

Comment: I do not think that is the expected output....OP is saying that one of the `0` is missing

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`non_zero`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html) from the `numpy` module. It has been designed to find all values different to 0.

And if you want to get all the zero, you can find them with [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```
l = [2, 3, 6, 0, 0, 5, 6, 0, 7]

import numpy as np
np_l = np.array(l)

non_zero = np_l[np.nonzero(np_l)]
print(non_zero)
# [2 3 6 5 6 7]

zero = np_l[np.where(np_l == 0)]
print(zero)
# [0 0 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby

l=[2,3,6,0,0,5,6,0,7]

non_zeros = []
zeros = []
for v, g in groupby(l, lambda k: k==0):
    if v:
        zeros.extend(g)
    else:
        non_zeros.extend(g)

print(non_zeros)
print(zeros)
```

Prints:

```
[2, 3, 6, 5, 6, 7]
[0, 0, 0]
```